# vim, vimdiff, ex, view, rvim and rview: How do they start in a different way when they are symlinks to the same binary?

Tags: linux, ex-mode

I just installed version 8 of Vim and notice in the `bin` directory of the install location that all the above mentioned programs point to the same binary – `vim`. Then, how does it know when I invoke `ex` to open in the `ex` mode and so on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside vim's source code, there is a main function roughly like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[0], "ex"))
        do_ex_setup();

    main_loop();

    return 0;
}
```

This function is where the operating system starts the execution of the vim executable. 
 The naming and arguments differ between operating systems, but we'll assume `-nix` style. 
  By convention, the shell passes words from the command line you typed as strings in the argv array when starting the program.  E.g.,

```
ex filename
```

becomes `char *argv[] = {"ex", "filename"};`

Similarly for `view`, `vimdiff`, etc.

Comment: You can try this yourself at home. Create a script: `echo $0`, add a symlink to it, and run the symlink.